# reading value from XML formatted response from jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am sending a request to a URL using `$.get()`. The response text returns with the following XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<myNode>
  <cmd>Requested Item</cmd>
  <myValue>this is the text i need to get with jquery</myValue>
  <res>OK</res>
</myNode>
```

I need to get the text inside the `<myValue>` and `</myValue>` tag:

```
<myValue>this is the text i need to get with jquery</myValue>
```

I have tried the following code inside $.get() function:

```
$.get(url,function(xml){
    var x, i, attnode, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('data');
}
```

but there is no value in variable `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the xml with `$` (jQuery) function, then you can use .find to find the node. Something like `$(xml).find('myValue').html()`

Demo (In this demo I'm not using ajax but the principle is the same):

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' +
    '<myNode>' + 
    '<cmd>Requested Item</cmd>' +
    '<myValue>this is the text i need to get with jquery</myValue>' +
    '<res>OK</res>' + 
    '</myNode>';

var x = $(xml).find('myValue').html();
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get(url,function(xml){
    var x, i, attnode, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml.responseXML );
    var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
    var myValue= $xml.find( "myValue" );
    console.log(myValue.text())
}
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: yes its also work. I notice that i have not search the result as $(xml) ... thanks again